# Persisting multiple entities and their relations (Cascade.All / ManyToMany)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I need to create a bunch of objects programatically and persist them all. 
There are `1:n`, `1:1` and `n:n` relations involved at the same time.

All relations are defined with `CascadeType.All`.

When I now create all the object instances and set their relations, only the first `persist()` operation will work. The others will fail with the message, that a detached entity has been passed to persist.

Example:

```
A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();
A a3 = new A();

CommonB = new B();
SpecialB = new B();

Set<B> set1 = new HashSet<B>();
set1.add(CommonB);
set1.add(SpecialB);

Set<B> set2 = new HashSet<B>();
set2.add(CommonB);

a1.setBs(set1);
a2.setBs(set2);
a3.setBs(set2);
```

Now, i'm using our dataservice to persist a1, a2 and a3. (It basically just calls persist() on the entitymanager)

The first attempt works well, Both, `CommonB` and `SpecialB` are persisted along with `a1` (also the relations are created. However, when i try to persist `a2`, Hibernate says `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: my.namespace.B`

Classes look like this:

```
class A(){
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable
    private Set<B> bs;

    //get set
}

class B(){
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "bs")
    private Set<A> as;
}
```

The example has been stripped down, in fact there are multiple `n:n` relations between 5 entities.

--- update

I missed to add the "As" to the "Bs" Set as well:

```
CommonB.setAs(/* a1, a2, a3 */);
SpecialB.setAs(/* a1 */);
```

So, saying the complete relations *are* set on the object level. 
Shouldn't `Cascade.All` actually take care of persisting ALL objects within a certain relation bunch, whenever I save ONE of those objects?

If i give like `em.persist(a1)`, shouldn't hibernate notice:

- a1 is related to CommonB and Special B.
- CommonB in turn is related to a2 and a3
- So i'm saving a1,a2,a3, CommonB and SpecialB.

However that is not going to happen..

Answer (score 2):

When you persist `a1`, it also persists the `CommonB` and sets id into that object. Persisting `a2` will try to persist  `CommonB` again while it has been persisted once. I assume your dataservice is Transactional, so after persisting `a1` it closes TX and Hibernate's session then `CommonB` becomes a detached object. You need to reload(re-attach) `CommonB` when persisting `a2` and `a3`.

Comment: That's true. I also forgot to add the "reverse" relations. I fixed it now, so `normaly` i should be able to persist ALL objects, when persisting once (see my edit) - however that is not going to happen. :(